# Calculate the area of a 2d closed polygon using numpy

Tags: numpy, array-broadcasting

I have a 2d numpy array, and I would like to evaluate the following equation.
Is there a numpy like(vectorized) way to implement this evaluation rather than just iterating over the values?

Bonus question, is there a way(vectorized again) to save each result of the product inside a new 1d numpy array?
Thanks in advance

btw, The formula was found from this site: [https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~ese502/lab-content/extra_materials/Polygon%20Area%20and%20Centroid.pdf](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/%7Eese502/lab-content/extra_materials/Polygon%20Area%20and%20Centroid.pdf)

[image]

Comment: Please provide some representative data and your corresponding expected result. It's unclear, to me at least, whether you have a list of coordinates of vertices, or a Numpy array of coordinates of vertices or a masked polygonal area within a Numpy array. Thank you.

Comment: Hello? Have you abandoned this question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [numpy.roll](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) as follows:

```py
import numpy as np

N = 5
a = np.random.rand(N, 2)
x, y = a[:,0], a[:,1]

area = 1/2 * np.sum(x*np.roll(y, 1) - y*np.roll(x, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here an implementation in SQF language:

```
private _n0 = count(_polygon);
private _surface = 0;

for "_i0" from 0 to (_n0 - 1) do {
    private _p1 = _polygon select _i0;
    private _p2 = _polygon select ((_i0 + 1) % _n0);
    private _p1x = _p1 select 0;
    private _p1y = _p1 select 1;
    private _p2x = _p2 select 0;
    private _p2y = _p2 select 1;
    _surface = _surface + ((_p1x * _p2y) - (_p2x * _p1y)) / 2;
```

You just need to translate it in python

Answer (score 0):

einsum is handy to implement the shoelace formula

```
A  # --- sample array representing a polygon ordered clockwise
array([[  0.00,   0.00],
       [  0.00,  10.00],
       [ 10.00,  10.00],
       [ 10.00,   0.00],
       [  0.00,   0.00]])

# --- can be implemented in a list comprehension of for loop

def _bit_area_(a):
    """Mini e_area, used by `areas` and `centroids`."""
    x0, y1 = (a.T)[:, 1:]
    x1, y0 = (a.T)[:, :-1]
    e0 = np.einsum('...i,...i->...i', x0, y0)
    e1 = np.einsum('...i,...i->...i', x1, y1)
    return np.sum((e0 - e1) * 0.5)
    

_bit_area_(A)
100.0  # --- result for a 10 x 10 unit square,
```